# Error when creating EMR cluster, EMR service role is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, permissions, aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr

I am creating an emr cluster through a cloudformation and lambda function. After the creation of stack, when I run the lambda function, it starts the cluster by gives EMR service role:is invalid error. My code for service roles and job flow roles are attached. Which is the permission I am missing or I should give in order for my emr to start executing the steps.

```
EMRClusterServiceRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
            - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonElasticMapReduceforEC2Role
      Path: /

  EMRClusterinstanceProfileRole: 
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: 
            Service: 
            - ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action: 
          - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns: 
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonElasticMapReduceforEC2Role
      Path: /

  EMRClusterinstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
      - !Ref EMRClusterinstanceProfileRole

  EMRJobFlowProfileinstance: 
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
      - !Ref EMRJobFlowRole


  EMRJobFlowRole:       
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: 
            Service: 
            - ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action: 
          - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns: 
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonElasticMapReduceforEC2Role
      Path: /
```

Comment: `EMRClusterServiceRole` has wrong indentation. Don't know if its due to copy-paste to SO or it is actually like this in your code.

Comment: The roles are getting created after the stack creation is completed. But when the emr is getting created it is giving me the above error. I also checked the indentation, it looks good.

Comment: Shoudn't EMR service role use `elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com` in its trust policy? EMR creates default roles. Check them, and compare with yours.

Comment: Yes it worked when I added the policies

Comment: Glad to hear. I will add an answer for future reference if you don't mind.

Comment: Sure, it will be easier for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, the solution was to use as `elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com` trust policy principle.